# Road route number in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, apple-maps

Is there any possible way to get a route number (eg. A1, A7, E2, 66...) of the road the user is currently driving on? I've been looking for a while now but haven't found any information on this topic. Also, I've seen in Apple's maps that most of the roads have their route number displayed.

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to stick with apple maps or are you willing to try out mapbox or google maps?

Comment: @DavidChopin yes, I'm currently only working with apple maps